# What will happen if @Singleton bean would have a @Stateless field in it?

Tags: java, singleton, ejb, stateless

I am not sure how does **@EJB** annotation assign the fields etc.

Let just assume we have 3 classes:

- A - **Stateless** (has a B field with **@EJB** annotation)
- B - **Singleton** (has a C field with **@EJB** annotation)
- C - **Stateless**

In this case, what will happen when user tries to access the beans?

1. User **1** accesses beans (first time)

   1. **A** is created and needs **B** to work so
   2. **B** is created and needs **C** to work so
   3. **C** is created
2. User 2 connects and

   1. **A** is created as user 1 is still using his **A**
   2. **B** is needed but it is a singleton so the only instance is returned
   3. **C** is not created as Singleton **B** has already assigned a reference to it

Does this mean that if **@Singleton** needs any other bean, the bean it will be used as **@Singleton**? (**@Stateless** will act as singleton)

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  If the singleton allows multiple concurrent calls with `@Lock(READ)` or `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)`, then multiple C beans will be created, one per caller thread the same as the A bean.  However, if the singleton bean is using the default concurrency of `@ConcurrencyManagement(CONTAINER)` with `@Lock(WRITE)`, then yes, bean C will effectively also be a singleton (assuming it's not accessed elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

i have created an example implementation for your question. you can find it on GitHub:
https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-28194928

open this project with NetBeans 8.0.2 and deploy (Run) this on Glassfish 4.1.

the following logs are created after deployment:

```
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   visiting unvisited references
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB C: [java:global/mavenproject1/C!com.mycompany.mavenproject1.C, java:global/mavenproject1/C]
Schwerwiegend:   C[uuid=e1c73e4b-998c-4666-bac9-4825556aa20a] => created
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB Bootstrap: [java:global/mavenproject1/Bootstrap!com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Bootstrap, java:global/mavenproject1/Bootstrap]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB A: [java:global/mavenproject1/A, java:global/mavenproject1/A!com.mycompany.mavenproject1.ARemote]
Information:   Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB A: [com.mycompany.mavenproject1.ARemote, com.mycompany.mavenproject1.ARemote#com.mycompany.mavenproject1.ARemote]
Information:   Portable JNDI names for EJB B: [java:global/mavenproject1/B!com.mycompany.mavenproject1.B, java:global/mavenproject1/B]
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=868f15c0-728d-4079-b90a-2b55ae413c33] => created
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Schwerwiegend:   ========================
Schwerwiegend:   Bootstrap.init()
Schwerwiegend:   ========================
Information:   mavenproject1 was successfully deployed in 419 milliseconds.
```

and now run only the focused test method ARemoteIT.client1(). the following output is generated:

```
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=9be077f8-945a-4db2-ba3e-ea0003692c0f] => created ()
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=9be077f8-945a-4db2-ba3e-ea0003692c0f] => B of type com.mycompany.mavenproject1.__EJB31_Generated__B__Intf____Bean__ injected
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=9be077f8-945a-4db2-ba3e-ea0003692c0f] => ready to use 
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=9be077f8-945a-4db2-ba3e-ea0003692c0f] [client1] => doSomething() called
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=ce1be5f1-0b82-4990-a9b5-153a2540a891] => created
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=ce1be5f1-0b82-4990-a9b5-153a2540a891] => C of type com.mycompany.mavenproject1.__EJB31_Generated__C__Intf____Bean__ injected
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=ce1be5f1-0b82-4990-a9b5-153a2540a891] => ready to use
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=ce1be5f1-0b82-4990-a9b5-153a2540a891] [client1]   => doSomething() called
Schwerwiegend:   C[uuid=5f1bed5c-80e8-41c8-b524-51cac3e3de0f] => created
Schwerwiegend:   C[uuid=5f1bed5c-80e8-41c8-b524-51cac3e3de0f] => ready to use
Schwerwiegend:   C[uuid=5f1bed5c-80e8-41c8-b524-51cac3e3de0f] [client1]     => doSomething() called
```

inside C.doeSomething() there is now a timeout for 1 minute...

inside this timeout the singleton bean B cannot be accessed concurrently, because the default lock type is Write (@Lock(WRITE)).

if you start now within the 1 minute timeout the fucused test method ARemoteIT.client2() the following output is generated:

```
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=c358e9f3-8687-4d76-a9ca-38b31357649b] => created ()
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=c358e9f3-8687-4d76-a9ca-38b31357649b] => B of type com.mycompany.mavenproject1.__EJB31_Generated__B__Intf____Bean__ injected
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=c358e9f3-8687-4d76-a9ca-38b31357649b] => ready to use 
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=c358e9f3-8687-4d76-a9ca-38b31357649b] [client2] => doSomething() called
```

here you can see that client2 is Waitung for B to call B.doSomething. after the timeout of 1 minute is done. the
singleton bean can be accessed and the client2 can following with B.doSomething.

here the logs after the timeout of client1 C.doSomething:

```
Schwerwiegend:   C[uuid=5f1bed5c-80e8-41c8-b524-51cac3e3de0f] [client1]     => doSomething() finished
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=ce1be5f1-0b82-4990-a9b5-153a2540a891] [client1]   => doSomething() finished
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=9be077f8-945a-4db2-ba3e-ea0003692c0f] [client1] => doSomething() finished
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=ce1be5f1-0b82-4990-a9b5-153a2540a891] [client2]   => doSomething() called
Schwerwiegend:   C[uuid=5f1bed5c-80e8-41c8-b524-51cac3e3de0f] [client2]     => doSomething() called
Schwerwiegend:   C[uuid=5f1bed5c-80e8-41c8-b524-51cac3e3de0f] [client2]     => doSomething() finished
Schwerwiegend:   B[uuid=ce1be5f1-0b82-4990-a9b5-153a2540a891] [client2]   => doSomething() finished
Schwerwiegend:   A[uuid=c358e9f3-8687-4d76-a9ca-38b31357649b] [client2] => doSomething() finished
```

**Additionals:**

as you can see. it is not really an instance of B or C where is injected! instead these are only proxies.
but you can also see that glassfish automatically creates new instances of B an C after deployment.

with @Stateless you have no guarantee that you receive the same instance of the required EJB. it could also be that
every time you call a method on your proxy you receive another instance of the required EJB. The container is managing this.
There is a pool of EJBs where the container uses one or create a new instance if there are all EJBs in use.

in the logs you see that B is only created after A.doSomething() is called. that mens at calling the method of the proxy.

Comment: sorry for all the updates i made on this answer.. but i think the UUID is required to see how many instances are created and used by which client...